# Audio playback under lockscreen in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, audio, microsoft-metro

I have a Windows 8.1 app where I need to play audio, also when the app is in background and under lockscreen.

In Package.appxmanifest, in the declarations section I add Background Task and set it to Audio. So far so good, the audio playback continues when U switch from the app to another app or to the desktop.

Now I need the playback to also continue under lockscreen, so I add the Badge Logo assets, and set Lock screen notifications: badge, so the app can work under lockscreen. But the project does not build:

```
App manifest defines lock screen notifications without specifying one of appropriate background task types: timer, control channel, push notification, or location.
```

But I do not need any of those functionalists. Adding one, like location, just so it builds and works seems really strange.

What is the correct setup to allow the app to play audio under lockscreen?